# Property 'set' does not exist on type 'FirebaseListObservable

Tags: angularfire2

I am trying to use angularfire2 `"angularfire2": "^4.0.0-rc.1",`. It gives me the error : `Property 'set' does not exist on type 'FirebaseListObservable`.

Code is

```
const userList:FirebaseListObservable<any> = this._angualrFireDB.list('/users');
userList.set(this.userAuthData.uid,tempUserData).then(...)
```

For some reason I cant use RC.2, due to not proper integration with cordova.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

There's an [open issue](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1051) in `angularfire2` regarding `set` support for lists.

Apparently is not fully implemented and should be removed from the docs.

Comment: For my use case I could handle directly with `update` setting the key.